2023 Q2 Activity Support
I'm opening another opportunity to request support for asking and answering questions on our site.
I will be accepting proposals here until Friday, June 23rd. I'm very open to input from anyone on this process. However, because I have to report back to TLG how these sets were used, final decisions over what is approved will be at my discretion. Important factors for me will be community feedback for a user's proposal (via comments and votes here), as well as the quality of content that a user generally creates.
I have some ideas I've been mulling over, but I'd love to spread this support around to support the community as much as possible.
Users submitting proposals must meet the following requirements:

You must have earned at least 200 rep in 2023 or 1k rep total.
You may not resell these sets. This is a TLG requirement.
You must be committed to completing your proposed work before the end of the year.

For this support request, we are restricted to the following:

667 EUR
10 items total, up to 5 copies of the same set
Maximum of 5 addresses on the request

Here are some possible ideas that I think would be valuable:

Answer an unanswered question. If there's a question that a set doesn't directly help you answer, that's alright. An unrelated set can still be provided as a "thank you" for your contribution. Here are some examples where a set could be helpful:

How much tension can I expect to get out of a LEGO chains before it starts to give away?
How To Ensure Only One Brick is Fed Into a Lego Sorting Machine at a Time?


Motorize the new Land Rover Defender
Motorize the new Hogwarts Express


Would love to try this one day but I struggle to think of a set that matches the question I’d like to answer.

@Ambo100 "An unrelated set can still be provided as a "thank you" for your contribution."

I could give the "LEGO chain tension measurement" question a shot (using a similar approach as I did with the train magnets), but I'd need some chain elements for that. As far as I can see, the set with the most chain link pieces currently in LEGO's offer would be 10303: Loop Coaster, which at 400€ would be at the higher end of the allowed price range. Other alternatives with their chainlinks/€ ratio would be:

10303: Loop Coaster 222 for 400€: 0.55
10273: Haunted House 148 for 300€: 0.49
75331: The Razor Crest - UCS 158 for 600€: 0.26
10323: PAC-MAN Arcade 66 for 270€: 0.24

Seeing that the question is about a 16 and a 24-tooth gear, I estimate the required length of the chain at 40-50 links. As the question proposes, breakage of the chain pieces is not impossible either, so the total number anticipating the eventual destruction of some of them should be about 60-70 depending on the number of tests to be conducted. There are other sets which contain chain pieces, but not in the required amount, so in these cases multiple sets would be needed:

42155: The Batman - Batcycle 45 for 55€: 0.81
42107: Ducati Panigale V4 R 35 for 70€: 0.5
42139: All-Terrain Vehicle 21 for 90€: 0.23


Sounds good to me. We can figure out which set(s) make the most sense once we know if others are interested in participating.

Set 42148, Snow Groomer, contains 56 m5 threads. At an MSRP of 9.99€ that gives it a chainlink/€ ratio of 5.6 and should give you plenty available parts. If I'm not mistaken they're identical to chain pieces in terms of linkage, they just have a plate added on top.

Do you have a personal preference between these sets? 1x of each of the Ducati and Batcycle seems like it would give you want you need, but if you're more excited about one of the larger sets we can probably make that work as well.

@jncraton Thanks for the offer - while of course I'd prefer one of the larger sets (the roller coaster looks pretty intriguing from a technical standpoint), I certainly don't want to impose, so let's settle for the Ducati and the Batcycle. The links with the plate as mentioned by MMM seem indeed to have the same interface, but as the question is about the plain version, I'd think to test with those, since different moulds might have different weaknesses.

Sounds good. When you have a chance, please send me you shipping info including a contact phone number. You can email this to my username at gmail.

@jncraton Sent an email, thank you for your hard work!

Posted my answer: https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/18267/3631 Thank you and TLG for making it possible!

I would like to give this a try too. A couple of questions that appeal to me are the ones on cleaning minifigs and changing yoshi's pose.
The first would just need a set with a bunch of minifigures, potentially 60134 Fun in the Park People Pack.
The second would obviously need a set with the default Yoshi pose, either 71367 Mario's House, or 71406 Yoshi's House.

I'm happy to move forward with either of both of these. The sets we request need to be listed as available on LEGO.com, or they will be dropped from our request when it is processed. Only 71406 is currently available. Would you like to move forward with that set, or do you have other ideas?

71418 and 71387 might also be helpful if you want additional Yoshi colors to experiment with.

I’m happy with 71406, and 71418 would be useful with blue being more common. I don’t own a lot of Bright Pink so that could be a challenge. I could make a digital model if I don’t have the parts.

I’ll drop the minifig cleaning question in favour of the more interesting one.

Sounds good. 71406 and 71418 make sense to me. When you have a chance, please email me (my username here at gmail) your shipping address along with contact phone number.
